# Plus sign in 3des encrypted url

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-5

I have a url that is created from a 3des function.  The webserver should decrypt this url and grab the parameters it needs.

However, the decrypt function is failing due to a plus sign in the string, the webserver (iis7, also on iis5) is reading this as a space.

I understand this is by design but is there any way to disable it?  I've added the following line into my web.config but to no avail!

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to urlencode the string before you use it. the plus will be encoded as %2b. asp.net & javascript both have functions to allow you to do this.

alternatively & less reliably do the opposite & look for spaces & put a + back in when you find one.

Comment: Ah! This crossed my mind earlier but I dismissed it for some reason.  Out of interest, why is it that I don;t need to decode after I've done the encode?  It works with just the encrypt > encode > decrypt.
Many thanks!

Comment: asp.net helpfully decodes the urls for you. which is why you need to encode in the first place.